ansible Q. RSA, passwd

Ansible Installation Completed

Host IP input completed in /etc/ansible/hosts

Attempt to ssh with each node - Enter password and succeed

Successful RSA [enter image description here][1]authorized_keys creation and copy commands to each node

SSH attempt to each node - successful entry without password

Complete entering user information into each node sudoers

Complete 400 permissions for each node .ssh 600 / 400 authorized_keys


​
***** Next step failed
uesr@DESKTOP-IEDPTL0:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ansible all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=present"
permission and password error
-Permission resolved with command -b
​uesr@DESKTOP-IEDPTL0:/mnt/c/Users/user$ ansible all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=present" -b
192.168.218.134 | FAILED! => {
"msg": "Missing sudo password"
​
-enter the password with the k-k command, but the password is different for each node, so you can't install it all at once with the all command
Obviously, I copied the certificate and I have regular ssh access, but why can't I recognize it on Ansible?
user1@user1:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 user1 user1 574 Aug 22 08:47 /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys

"Missing sudo password" is not a ssh problem, it is a sudo problem.
Run with verbosity 3, so ansible-playbook -vvv  and read the executed commands carefully. Become enabled commands will be wrapped in sudo on the remote host.  Further, check against sudo policy. You can allow specific commands to run without a password, but how Ansible runs commands in shell will not work in such an allow list.

Passwords are a poor auth mechanism. Even worse in an non-interactive use case, where the plain text password has to be available, it is not typed in by a human.  Do your best to remove password auth. At least as an exception for automation users.
However, Ansible can accommodate many kinds of legacy systems.
 -K (capital) aka --ask-become-pass  is an interactive prompt for sudo (or doas, or runas, there are a few become plugins).  It is not host specific and only prompts once.  So it only works if the password is the same on every host.
As an alternative, there are several ways to provide become configuration, notably special variables such as  ansible_become_password
All Ansible variables can be defined in host specific ways.  For example, say an Ansible lookup plugin exists for a secret storage system you use. Then you could write an expression, referencing the magic variable inventory_hostname, that returns the secret.
Combine these concepts and set ansible_become_password to whatever expression returns the password.
